# Is zookeeper 3.6.0 version compatible with kafka 2.2.1 version

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, apache-zookeeper, log4shell

We are currently using kafka 2.2.1 version and zookeeper 3.5.9 version. We are trying to upgrade zookeeper to 3.6.0 because of log4j workaround (as zookeeper 3.6 as no explicit dependency with log4j1.x)

Unfortunately we cannot upgrade kafka to a higher version currently.

Can someone please suggest is zookeeper 3.6.0 compatible with kafka 2.2.1?

Also where can I find this kafka and zookeeper version compatibility, if at all we want to upgrade kafka we want to know which zookeeper version is compatible with which kafka version.

Answer (score 0):

> where can I find this kafka and zookeeper version compatibility

You can look at Kafka source code on Github to see what version of Zookeeper clients are included in the code.

> Is Zookeeper X compatible with Kafka Y

There is no easy way to tell. The projects aren't direct related. You need to read Zookeeper release notes to find breaking changes.

Zookeeper 3.5.x has been end-of-life for over a year now, but `3.5.10` is a **much** safer option to upgrade to (which also has `reload4j`), over `3.6.x` from `3.5.9`. (`3.6.x` is also end-of-life)

There is no reason to upgrade Zookeeper before upgrading Kafka. Unless [otherwise mentioned](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade)

Plus, [as written in Zookeeper releases](https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html)

> ZooKeeper clients from 3.5.x onwards are **fully compatible** with **3.8.x** servers

3.7 releases say something similar.

Zookeeper 3.8 uses logback now, and not log4j / reload4j

---

> cannot upgrade kafka to a higher version currently

Kafka brokers are backwards compatible (with few exceptions). Do a rolling upgrade, and there should be no downtime for clients.

Kafka `3.2.0` is the earliest with log4j changes to reload4j